# CSS not loading in M2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin

For some reason when i log in to the admin panel It's not loading the CSS and possibly JS.

Has anyone encountered this issue, could it be related to these errors?

> main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxx/pub/static/frontend/xxxx/xxx/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxx/pub/static/frontend/xxxx/xxx/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:71)"} []
>   [2018-04-24 17:04:01] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxx/pub/static/frontend/xxxx/xxx/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException(code: 0):

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove the folders from

```
  rm -rf /var/cache/*
  rm -rf /var/generation/*
  rm -rf /pub/static/*
```

after that following command run on magento root

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php bin/magento cache:clean
```